# bfs using an adjacent list implentation debug

Tags: c++, queue, graph-theory, breadth-first-search, adjacency-list

I am trying to debug a bfs algorithm using a adjacent list. It will print correctly to a certain point then goes into infinite loop. I did some printouts and noticed that it eventually loops over the first two nodes of the graph. I am not sure where in my code thats causing this problem. This is anassignment I was given, and this is my last resort. If anyone can point me in the right direction as to what the problem could be would help alot.

```
void bfsList(linkedList adjList[], int visit[], int j){
    Queue queue(24);
    if (visit[j] == 0){
        cout << j+1 << endl;
        visit[j] = 1;
        queue.enqueue(j);
        while(!queue.isEmpty()){
            int k = queue.dequeue();
            //queue.print();
            for(int i=0;i<adjList[k].len();i++){
                if (visit[adjList[k].elementAt(i)-1]==0){
                    cout << adjList[k].elementAt(i) << endl;
                    visit[adjList[k].elementAt(i)-1] = 1;
                }
                if (!queue.isFull()){
                    queue.enqueue(adjList[k].elementAt(i)-1);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have also checked the adjacency list. There is nothing wrong with the list as it is the same one I used for my implementation of the depth first search. the graph is loaded from a csv file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enqueue only if node is not visited.

```
if (visit[adjList[k].elementAt(i)-1]==0){
    cout << adjList[k].elementAt(i) << endl;
    visit[adjList[k].elementAt(i)-1] = 1;

    if (!queue.isFull()){
    queue.enqueue(adjList[k].elementAt(i)-1);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you both, I did what you said but I updated the visit array after the enqueue

Answer (score 0):

```
queue.enqueue(adjList[k].elementAt(i)-1);
```

needs to be dependent, whether the node has been visited.
untested:

```
if (!queue.isFull() && !visit[adjList[k].elementAt(i)-1]){
                queue.enqueue(adjList[k].elementAt(i)-1);
            }
```

Comment: I tried that prior to posting and it only prints out the first node then the second node. To my understanding of bfs is that though it may visit the node. it will need to be enqueued to get the their neighbouring nodes. so If I do the check there it will stop after it prints the neighbouring node for the first node.

Comment: Thank you both, I did what you said but I updated the visit array after the enqueue